# How do I select a dynamic ID represented by a ruby instance variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a `div` whose ID is populated by an instance variable in my view:

```
<div class="card" id="card-<%= @card_number %>">
```

In my `create.js.erb`, how do I select that div?

I tried this:

```
$('#<%= @card_id %> .card-comments').prepend("<%= j (render partial: 'nodes/comment', locals: { comment: @comment}) %>");
```

But it doesn't work and outputs a blank value for the ID in the selector. How do I get it to select the correct ID?

I also tried `$('#<%= j @card_id %> .card-comments').prepend...` but that doesn't work either.

**Edit 1**

This is the code that generates that dynamic ID suffix in the view:

```
    <% @card_number = 0 %>
      <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
        <% @card_number += 1 %>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l4 card-container">
          <div class="card" id="card-<%= @card_number %>">
            <!-- Card Content -->
```

That generates HTML like this:

```
<div class="card" id="card-2">
```

**Edit 2**

The action in my controller that calls `create.js.erb` is the `CommentController#Create`. This is what it looks like:

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.node = @node
    @card_id = params[:card_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save and @node.save
        format.html
        format.js
      else
        format.html # { render action: 'new' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit 3**

This is the code that generates the form:

```
<div class="card-input">
  <%= simple_form_for([node, Comment.new], html: { id: "new_comment_card-#{@card_number}"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
   <%= f.input_field :message, as: :text, id: "card-input-field-#{@card_number}", class: "input-field", placeholder: "Share your thoughts", cols: "30", rows: "10" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, name: "card_id", value: "card-#{@card_number}", class: "input-submit" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Edit 4**

When the form is submitted, this is what the server log looks like:

```
Started POST "/nodes/86/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-13 23:22:26 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"message"=>"Form Video Comment 5."}, "card_id"=>"card-2", "node_id"=>"86"}
  User Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (7.8ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
  Role Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Node Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 86]]
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (5.1ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("created_at", "message", "node_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-07-14 04:22:26.760577"], ["message", "Form Video Comment 5."], ["node_id", 86], ["updated_at", "2015-07-14 04:22:26.760577"], ["user_id", 57]]
  SQL (6.2ms)  UPDATE "nodes" SET "comments_count" = COALESCE("comments_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "nodes"."id" = 86
   (3.3ms)  COMMIT
   (7.7ms)  BEGIN
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered nodes/_comment.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (11.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 351ms (Views: 29.3ms | ActiveRecord: 46.2ms)
```

Notice the `params[:card_id] = 'card-2'`

Comment: can you add the controller code, basically if blank value comes in the selected that means no value is present in `@card_id`

Comment: Is element with class named `.card-comments` present inside `card-<%= @card_number %>` and when you do `$('#<%= @card_id %> .card-comments')` it will search for element with class `.card-comments` inside `card-<%= @card_number %>`

Comment: @Coderhs Nah there is a value in `@card_id`. I can tell by simply viewing the source of the HTML and I see that it generates the DIV with IDs: `card-1, card-2, etc.` which is what the value is for. That value is set in the view, not the controller right now. I will refactor later, but just want to get it working first.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, it is inside `card-<%= @card_number %>` div. Ideally I would like for it to search for a div with class `card_comments` that is a child of another div with ID `card-<%= @card_number %>`.

Comment: You said "That value is set in the view, not the controller right now" please share the code which set that value please.

Comment: so the `id` gets generated dynamically here right? and if am not wrong this line -> `card-<%= @card_number %>` might get replaced with `card-1`, `card-2` etc.?

Comment: @SoufyaneBouchaala I have updated the question with both the code that generates the view and an example of the HTML produced.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, you are correct. I have updated the question with both the code that generates it and the HTML produced.

Comment: your html.erb is fine, I need to see where is `@card_id = somthing` in your code

Comment: Then I think you have to select with exact `cardnumber` like instead of `$('#<%= @card_id %> .card-comments')` it should have been `$('#card-2 .card-comments')` right? because `jquery` gets the elements once it is appended in the DOM

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes, but I don't know when it will be the exact element ID - so I have to use a dynamically created `@card_id` or `@card_number`.

Comment: To tell about that you might need to give some details on what instance you are calling this `jquery` method

Comment: @SoufyaneBouchaala you are right. I edited the question to show where `@card_id` comes from - which is from the create action in the controller that generates the `create.js.erb`.

Comment: Oops!! Sorry to say but I am not good with Ruby-on-Rails, in fact I've never worked on it.. So am not able to understand the logic of calling the code here..

Comment: can you show js output? your code looks good.

Comment: @SoufyaneBouchaala Actually....it is working now. I had some JS that governs the view this is on, and I thought it was triggering this submit when it wasn't. The simple_form `f.button` is governing that. So this is all working now. It used to work and then it stopped working when I changed some stuff, I just couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

If in Rails view, it is

```
<div class="card" id="card-<%= @card_number %>">
```

Then for Javascript, you should use:

```
$("#card-<%= @card_id %>")
```

Comment: That's what I thought too....well technically you have an error. In the selector it should be `@card_number` not `@card_id`. Either way, I tried both and it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not useful at all, you can't just guess and answer! please read comments above.